# Single word for "very expensive"

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a single word for "very expensive".

It is going to be used, e.g.,

> I bought [very expensive] software.

Comment: Did you check a thesaurus? 'exorbitant'?

Comment: @NVZ However late it is, it popped up on the 'close' list, so I commented.

Comment: @NVZ A comment to the OP is also a comment for everyone else to see. My admonition to use a thesaurus is a more specific statement than simply a vote to close as off topic for lack of research.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try *extravagant*:

> Excessively high
>
> Extravagant expenses; extravagant prices.

[Extravagant definition by Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/extravagant)

Or if you believe that price to be unreasonably high, you can try
 *exorbitant*.

> Exceeding the bounds of custom, propriety, or reason, especially in
>   amount or extent; highly excessive:
>
> To charge an exorbitant price; exorbitant luxury.

[Exorbitant definition by Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/exorbitant)

Comment: Why was my answer down voted? There seems to be no reason why.

Answer (score 2):

> **exorbitant |ɪgˈzɔːbɪt(ə)nt|**
>   *adjective*
>   (of a price or amount charged) unreasonably high: some hotels charge exorbitant rates for phone calls.

---

Source: ODE

Answer (score 1):

Good words offered so far.  Also,

**pricey**

Answer (score 0):

**dear**

> expensive.
>
> "five pounds—that's a bit dear!"
>
> synonyms:  expensive, costly, high-cost, high-priced, highly priced, overpriced, exorbitant, extortionate; immoderate, extravagant, lavish, valuable; upmarket, over the odds; informalpricey, steep, stiff
>
> "the dining car served rather dear meals"

Another word is:
**pricey** which means very expensive